# Does servo monito annotation works out of the box?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, netflix-servo

I have write a method like that:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10_000)
@Monitor(name = "componentMonitor", type = DataSourceType.COUNTER)
public int method() {
    log.info("ping");
    return RandomUtils.nextInt();
}
```

It is invocated and `ping` appears in console, but `componentMonitor` do not appears into `/metrics` this metric is not send to `org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ExportMetricReader`. So how configurated servo/spectacor to make `@Monitor` annotations work?

**Note**

Reporting other metric via `com.netflix.spectator.api.Registry` works. So generally metric reporting and servo itself work.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't. I think you can use `Monitors.newObjectMonitor(id, object)` to get it to work. There is no aspect or anything to auto-create the `Monitor`.

Comment: So what is `Monitor` annotation used for?

Comment: Netflix uses it heavily. Whenever they create an object they call `Monitors.newObjectMonitor()`.

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that you need to register a MonitorRegistryMetricPoller for the @Monitor to work:

```
private void schedule(MetricPoller poller, List<MetricObserver> observers) {
    final PollRunnable task = new PollRunnable(poller, BasicMetricFilter.MATCH_ALL,
            true, observers);
    PollScheduler.getInstance().addPoller(task, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}

private void initMetricsPublishing() {
    final List<MetricObserver> observers = new ArrayList<>();

    final AmazonCloudWatchClient cloudWatchClient =
            new AmazonCloudWatchClient(awsCredentials);
    cloudWatchClient.setEndpoint(String.format("monitoring.%s.amazonaws.com", REGION));
    AwsTaggingCloudWatchMetricObserver cloudWatchMetricObserver = new AwsTaggingCloudWatchMetricObserver("cloudwatch",
            "Nomp", cloudWatchClient);
    observers.add(cloudWatchMetricObserver);
    PollScheduler.getInstance().start();
    schedule(new MonitorRegistryMetricPoller(), observers);  // <--- this
    schedule(new JvmMetricPoller(), observers);
    schedule(new TomcatPoller(), observers);
}
```